# How can i ignore Uppercase or lowercase in ado.net linq to sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

i have this query i want the user to search with the name without uppercase or lowercase  ,
how can i do this ?

````
                            join Materiel in ds.Materiel on Accessoir.id_mat equals Materiel.id_mat
                            join Client in ds.Client on Materiel.Client equals Client.Id
                            join TypeMateriel in ds.Type_mat on Materiel.TypeMat equals TypeMateriel.id_type_mat
                            join Atelier in ds.Atelier on Materiel.id_mat equals Atelier.id_mat
                            join Maint in ds.Maintenancier on Atelier.id_main equals Maint.id_main
                            join NomAtelier in ds.NomAtelier on Atelier.NomAtelier equals NomAtelier.NomAtelier
                            join Ticket in ds.Ticket on Atelier.numero_ticket equals Ticket.numero_ticket
                            where Client.Nom.Contains(textBox1.Text)
                            select new
                            {
                                Client_Nom = Client.Nom,
                                Client_Prenom = Client.Prenom,
                                Client_Telephone = Client.Telephone,
                                Nom_Materiel = Materiel.nom_mat,
                                Date_Entree = Materiel.date_entree,
                                Date_Maintenance = Materiel.date_maintenance,
                                Accessoir = Accessoir.nom_accessoir,
                                Pannes = Materiel.pannes,
                                Statut = Materiel.statut_mat,
                                Prix = Materiel.prix,
                                Nom_Atelier = NomAtelier.NomAtelier,
                                Ticket = Ticket.numero_ticket
                            };```
````

Comment: SqlServer usually already ignores casing when comparing strings (a "CI" in a collation stands for "Case Insensitive")

Comment: As @HansKeﬆing wrote, Usually, string comparisons are case-insensitive. If your database is configured to case sensitive collation  you can do this way

`...where Client.Nom.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())`

Comment: @ ɐsɹǝʌ ǝɔıʌ 's comment is the right Answer for your Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Posting here as an answer based on ɐsɹǝʌ ǝɔıʌ's, it's useful for other community members as well.
- In your code, change the where condition like below,
- First make it **Client.Nom** either **Upper** or **lower** case then search with the user input.

```cs
where Client.Nom.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())
```